# How to Set Firefox 4 to only store History for a set period of time, i.e. one day?

Tags: history, firefox

I want to setup Firefox 4 to only store my history for 1 day (or some other set period of time), but I can't seem to find an option to do that in the options dialog, all I can see is "Remember History", "Never Remember History" and "Custom History Settings". "Custom History Settings" only lets me select what to keep, not for how long.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Too bad, it seems one can no longer use [`browser.history_expire_days`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.history_expire_days) to force the cache to be deleted. [Written](http://blog.bonardo.net/2010/01/20/places-got-async-expiration) in January 2010:

> Originally expiration was managed by History component itself on three major steps: after each visit, during idle, at shutdown. [..] The new component is a JS component, it runs expiration in steps, every 3 minutes, with a simple adaptive algorithm, so that if the last step did not expire enough, the next one will be run later, while if it finds more items than the expired ones, the next step will expire more!

Somehow the Firefox folks think limiting history is just about *performance*, not about *privacy*:

> The new component is able to detect your hardware specs, especially memory size, and adapt expiration to it, this means you don't need anymore to tweak number of days of history, or whatever.

And so:

> [..] hidden expiration preferences have gone, so `browser.history_expire_days`, `browser.history_expire_days_min`, `browser.history_expire_sites` are now replaced by a single `places.history.enabled` preference.

...though:

> [..] two new hidden preferences: `places.history.expiration.interval_seconds` is number of seconds between each expiration step, while `places.history.expiration.max_pages` is maximum number of pages that we will retain before expiring.

(In old versions one could go into `about:config` and change `browser.history_expire_days` and [`browser.history_expire_days_min`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.history_expire_days_min). The latter is still present in Firefox 4 beta on my Mac, but probably not used. The first is gone altogether. In the older versions, according to [some article](http://blogs.n1zyy.com/n1zyy/2008/09/16/firefoxs-history-setting/), one might actually have wanted to add `browser.history_expire_days` manually.)

Note that deleted history entries might in fact [still be stored in the database](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q12) `places.sqlite`, just being *marked* as deleted. [Vacuuming that file](https://superuser.com/questions/5083/firefox-how-to-speed-up-the-smart-location-bar-awesomebar/5185#5185) compacts it, removing everything that is supposed to be deleted. And as an aside: this is not all history that is kept on your computer. Like Flash [keeps its own trail](https://superuser.com/questions/1627/how-to-automatically-remove-flash-history-privacy-trail-or-stop-flash-from-stori) too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Expire history by days](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/expire-history-by-days/) extension to restore the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you type `about:config` in your address bar and then filter for `history` you'll find the entries `browser.history_expire_days` and `browser.history_expire_days_min`. Try setting those to 1 day.

I'm not using Firefox 4, so I can't test this now, but I assume those options are still present.

Answer (score 1):

History expiration is now controlled [in an unusual way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places/Places_Expiration):

> Expiration is based on hardware specs, specifically on memory size and CPU cores. This means on mobile and old systems expiration will be more aggressive than on high-end hardware, to try keep the database size at a reasonable (and performant) value.

But it is still configurable via `about:config` preferences, use this one:

> *places.history.expiration.max_pages*: The maximum number of pages that may be retained in the database before starting to expire. Default value is calculated on startup and put into the *places.history.expiration.transient_current_max_pages* preference. This transient version of the preference is just mirroring the current value used by expiration, setting it won't have any effect.

So you can make its value smaller or greater to shorten or prolong expiration time correspondingly.