# Limiting Firefox 4 history

Tags: firefox, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Set Firefox 4 to only store History for 1 Day?](https://superuser.com/questions/197849/how-to-set-firefox-4-to-only-store-history-for-1-day)

I know that it is no longer possible to limit FF4's browser history by date. The recommended solution is to change `places.history.expiration.max_pages` to whatever number of pages you want stored. Unfortunately this is not working for me; the browser seems to ignore that number. Are there any other ways to limit the history?