# My firefox scrolling is jerky and very slow - how can I fix this?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

I have already turned 'smooth scrolling' on and have downloaded a plugin called 'smooth scrolling'.

Whenever I scroll down, the browser movement is very jerky and slow. It is pretty much unusable.

However, scrolling in a div with `overflow: auto` (like the related questions div above the question input textarea) scrolls fine.

I am using Windows XP freshly installed with Firefox 3.5.1

Anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check that you've got the right video drivers in place - last time I experienced slow scrolling (though this was across all applications) the problem was a brain-dead "default" driver.

Comment: You were right on the money!

Answer (score 3):

smooth scrolling is actually very cpu intensive, though it seems like the video drivers were your problem, sometimes 'smooth' scrolling can actually be the opposite, especially on older computers.

If you feel firefox is slower, try disabling smooth scrolling and see if things speed up.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html
Add the following to the userChrome.css

```
/* Improve scroll performance on slow machines on some sites. */
* {
  background-attachment: scroll !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but sometimes Firefox scrolls jerky (or freezes altogether) for a short moment after loading a page, after which it scrolls fine. For me, this was once related to a huge `places.sqlite` database file, which stores the history and bookmarks. When entries are removed from that database (like when history expires) or maybe even when they're changed, then unused space may not be automatically released. For me, manually running the `vacuum` command helped a lot.

(Some instructions on running `vacuum` on a Mac at [Firefox on Mac: Slow, slow, slow](https://superuser.com/questions/3275/firefox-on-mac-slow-slow-slow/3739#3739). Simular instructions apply to other operating systems.)

Answer (score 0):

check your video drivers...go to device drivers and look for the "yellow exclamation" mark.  You may need to uninstall and then reinstall your video drivers.  The drivers may have become corrupt after a previous installation or uninstall of different software.