# firefox starts too slowly 

Tags: windows, firefox

I have installed Firefox 3.6 and also have installed 19 significant plug-ins/add-ons [and also 3 many themes]. Firefox had been suffering from slow start-up bug since a long time. but I was happy to know that it was fixed in version 3.5.1 reading [this report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=501605)

If it true, then why I am still facing slow start-up problem? Is that because of too many plug-ins? Or because of automatic update checking[for plug-ins/add-ons] before start-up? Or because of 3.6 itself [I mean should I downgrade to 3.5.X ?] ??

I need Firefox, because of its mind-blowing plug-ins,

Comment: See "What is Firefox doing?" at http://superuser.com/questions/55754/what-is-firefox-doing or "Firefox on Mac: Slow, slow, slow" at http://superuser.com/questions/3275/firefox-on-mac-slow-slow-slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try shutting off some extensions or add ons that you have running. . also maybe roll back a version if you rather do that.

Comment: I guess you are right .. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to download and install the [Firefox Preloader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffpreloader/).

It is simply a utility that is designed to load parts of Mozilla Firefox into memory before it is used, to improve its startup time.

I have used this tool with earlier versions and it made a significant difference in load times.

Comment: Keep in note however, that the prefetcher in Windows (Vista and beyond) does a very good job in keeping the programs you use most around. And most importantly, you don't have another process around that just eats memory.

Comment: But I am sorry to report this, it couldn't make any difference .. I installed it and used for a day .. experiencing the same delay .. :-|

Answer (score 0):

If no other ideas come to light to explain the problem, I suggest disabling each plug-in, one by one, and seeing if that affects FF startup. If you find one that does seem to be the culprit, you can determine how often you use it and whether you want to leave it disabled except when you really need it in order to gain speed at restart, or maybe you use it so often it's worth the slow-down to you.

If it's only startup that's affected, what about just leaving FF up & running?